# Sony WF-1000XM3 - turn off the voice assistant

Tags: iphone, headphones, siri

Using a Sony bluetooth WF-1000XM3 headset on iOS15.

[image: Sony WF-1000XM3]

I hate the voice assistant on this headset. It has called several people without my knowledge, random people in my contacts. Pressing the right ear for several seconds activates it, and apparently I've done that now and then. I really had no clue I did that.

No matter if I turn the controls on or off with the Sony Headphones app, no matter if I remove that app, it activates voice control. I don't use Siri on this phone, have never used it, so I'm wondering if this *is* Siry or not? What type of voice recognition is this?

Is there a way to disable this "feature"? Is an iOS action an option?

Comment: Could you ask the assistant "Who are you?" It will return a response of "I'm Alexa. You can activate me..."; "I am Siri"; or "I am your Google Assistant. How can I help you?". If it is Siri, you can just disable Siri as a whole on your phone: https://www.howtogeek.com/667895/how-to-disable-siri-on-your-iphone-and-ipad. If it is anything else, I can help you (since its a more detailed process).

Comment: Did this help you? Please let me know if you need further instruction.